# How to assign a value to dynamic checkboxes C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a seating plan for cinema. I will have many dynamic checkboxes in different panels. Each panel will have different ticket rate. How can I assign the interger or string value for the checkboxes. This is my code

```
 for (int m = 1; m <= 20; m++)
        {
            CheckBox ck = new CheckBox();

            ck.ID = m.ToString();
            ck.Text = "C " + m.ToString();
            ck.Height = 40;
            ck.Width = 50;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(ck);

        }
```

Comment: Checkboxes can't have values, they're ticket or not ticked.

Comment: If ticked, I want to get the value. Or can I set the value to each panel?

Comment: You could put something in the Tag property of the checkbox. But why not create your own usercontrol checkbox that has a rate/value field where you can store your ticket price...

Comment: Define what you mean with **value** for a checkbox

Comment: I mean the ticket rate

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom attributes to any WebControl along with the CheckBox as follows.

```
checkBox.Attributes["customAttr"] = "Something you'd like to check later";
```

Comment: Just remember that these values can be modified Client Side. So storing ticket rates may not be the best approach here.

Comment: A reference value for the actual ticket rate can solve such problems.